# Bar Chart from Dataframe Error module 'numpy' has no attribute 'arrange'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plot

I am trying to plot a bar chart from a dataframe. If I do numpy arrange I see the error `module 'numpy' has no attribute 'arrange'` . If I don't do arrange I see no error but the chart opens but I don't see any bars.
Here's my code:

```
data = []
for x in tracks:
    data.append({'Track_Name':x.title,'plays':str(x.playback_count)})
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = df[['Track_Name']] 
df2 = df[['plays']]
df1 = str(df1)
df2 = str(df2)
ind = np.arrange(df1)
plt.bar(ind,df2)
plt.show()
```

---

### Plot Figure:

[image]

Comment: The function you are looking for is probably [`np.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html), not `np.arrange`. Also note that `np.arange` expects an integer argument, not a string.

Comment: Thanks very much unutbu, didn't know that arrange only expects integer. Which function would you suggest?

Comment: It would be helpful to see `df.to_dict('list')` so we can reproduce your situation and maybe better understand how to help you.

Comment: Correction: `np.arange` can accept floats as well.

Comment: Cool thanks for the correction. Regarding the df.to_dict('list'). This is the output:
{'Track_Name': ['Silvestre - Sport Theories 12" Snippets ( PH002 )', 'Renato - Alo Alo 12" Snippets ( PH001 )', 'Lenha', 'Nuvens', 'Vou lá fora buscar água', 'Untitled'], 'plays': ['1448', '1505', '936', '452', '354', '324']}

Comment: Does the output helps you in anyway? :)

Comment: `np.arange` accepts numbers (e.g. integer, float), not strings, or dataframes, or lists or other objects).

Comment: Thanks both. From the output, do you think the reason why I cannot see the bars in the chart is because the two columns from the dataframe have different types? Because If I don't arrange I can see the values in the chart on the x and y axis. Just not the bars :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a Pandas DataFrame, you can plot a bar graph of the `Track_Name` column vs `plays` using `df.plot(kind='bar', x='Track_Name', y='plays')`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame( {'Track_Name': ['Silvestre - Sport Theories 12" Snippets ( PH002 )', 'Renato - Alo Alo 12" Snippets ( PH001 )', 'Lenha', 'Nuvens', 'Vou lá fora buscar água', 'Untitled'], 'plays': ['1448', '1505', '936', '452', '354', '324']})
df['plays'] = df['plays'].astype(int)

df.plot(kind='bar', x='Track_Name', y='plays')
plt.xticks(rotation=10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

For very long `Track_Name`s, another possibility is to make a horizontal bar graph. 
Below, `ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels` is used to shorten long `Track_Names`. (Note you could also use `ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels` to shorten the x-ticklabels above if you wish):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame( {'Track_Name': ['Silvestre - Sport Theories 12" Snippets ( PH002 )', 'Renato - Alo Alo 12" Snippets ( PH001 )', 'Lenha', 'Nuvens', 'Vou lá fora buscar água', 'Untitled'], 'plays': ['1448', '1505', '936', '452', '354', '324']})
df['plays'] = df['plays'].astype(int)

ax = df.plot(kind='barh', x='Track_Name', y='plays')
ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels([item if len(item) < 10 else '{}...{}'.format(item[:5], item[-5:]) for item in df['Track_Name']])
plt.show()
```

[image]